# How can I streamline code to run multiple pipelines in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Referring to this example (https://ryan-reilly.medium.com/gridsearch-pipelines-of-multiple-models-on-multiclass-classification-e9124b6ea2e3), how can I write succinct code to run multiple models with hyperparameter tuning using Pipeline?

I've extracted a sample of the code (using only 2 models) below for reference. Looking at the code, some parts are repetitive e.g., repeating `('scaler', StandardScaler())` as well as setting GridSearchCV with `scoring = 'accuracy', cv=3`. Relatedly, is there a way to do a for loop to simply the code further using the naming conventions for the Pipeline objects and the parameters?

```
pipe_lr = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
                    ('lr', LogisticRegression(random_state=1))])
pipe_dt = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
                     ('dt', DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1))])

lr_param_grid = [{'lr__penalty':['l1','l2'], 
                  'lr__C': [1.0, 0.5, 0.1], 
                  'lr__solver': ['liblinear']}]

dt_param_grid = [{'dt__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 
                  'dt__min_samples_leaf': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                  'dt__max_depth': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                  'dt__min_samples_split': [0.5, 0.1]}]

lr_grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_lr, param_grid=lr_param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=3)
dt_grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe_dt, param_grid=dt_param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=3)

grids = [lr_grid_search, dt_grid_search]
for pipe in grids:
    pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Hey, are you looking to have one model at the end doing blending or stacking. Or do you to train multiple models with just one pipeline ?

Comment: I've added onto the sample code to show what I eventually plan to do i.e., simply run the various models (along with hyperparameter tuning). In essence, I wondered whether there is a shorter way of writing the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? You can add multiple models to the `models` list, as long as you add a dictionary to the `param_grids` list. The training loop will be the same for every model.
I also added a test if a model needs Standard scaling. Decision trees/Random Forests don't need it, and personally I just omit it then. I used `make_pipeline`, which does its own naming (just the classifier in lowercase).

```
models = [LogisticRegression(random_state=1),
          DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)]

param_grids = [{'logisticregression__penalty':['l1','l2'], 
                'logisticregression__C': [1.0, 0.5, 0.1], 
                'logisticregression__solver': ['liblinear']},
                {'decisiontreeclassifier__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 
                 'decisiontreeclassifier__min_samples_leaf': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                 'decisiontreeclassifier__max_depth': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                 'decisiontreeclassifier__min_samples_split': [0.5, 0.1]}]

for model, param_grid in zip(models, param_grids):
    if type(model) in [LogisticRegression, SVC]:  # just an example, add/remove classes from the list as you wish
        pipe = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(), model)
    else:
        pipe = make_pipeline(model)
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=3)
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Edit: This doubles the code, but if you don't want the long names in the `param_grids`, you can change the code to the following:

```
models = {'lr': LogisticRegression(random_state=1),
          'dt': DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)}

param_grids = [{'lr__penalty':['l1','l2'], 
                'lr__C': [1.0, 0.5, 0.1], 
                'lr__solver': ['liblinear']},
               {'dt__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'], 
                'dt__min_samples_leaf': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                'dt__max_depth': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                'dt__min_samples_split': [0.5, 0.1]}]

for (m_name, model), param_grid in zip(models.items(), param_grids):
    if type(model) in [LogisticRegression, SVC]:  # just an example, add/remove classes from the list as you wish
        pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), (m_name, model)])
    else:
        pipe = Pipeline([(m_name, model)])
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=3)
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant! Thanks as well for adding the scaling portion.

However, there are issues with the code because of the keys in the param_grids dictionaries - in this version of the code, I don't label `LogisticRegression` to `lr` and hence, when I get to `grid_search.fit()`, there's an error

Comment: Your're right, I fixed that. I also added a second version with your old naming. Both versions work now. I forgot about the naming in the `param_grids`. Now that I look at it, I like the second version a bit more, as the names in the `param_grids` is clearer.